# .startswith() issue on discord.py command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command where you can ask a question starting with "why" (for example why is grass green?) but I also want it to be .lower() so you can do "Why" or "WHY" instead of all lowercase. Problem is it isn't detecting anything in the argument of "question" as "why"

```py
@client.hybrid_command(name="askwhy",with_app_command=True,description="Ask the bot a question starting with 'Why'")
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.cooldown(1,7,BucketType.user)
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = 1009907559391567912))
async def askwhy(ctx, *, question = None):
  if question == None:
    await ctx.reply("Ask a question!")
  else:
    if not question.startswith("why") or not question.startswith("Why") or not question.startswith("WHY") or not question.startswith("WHy") or not question.startswith("wHY") or not question.startswith("whY"):
      await ctx.reply("Your question needs to start with `why` followed by the question")
    else:
      choices = ["Because I said so", "Idk", "Are you dumb? Everyone knows the answer.", "Google it.", "Ask your dad- My bad I forgot he left to get the milk..", "Hmm.. Try again later"]
      choice = random.choice(choices)
      await ctx.typing()
      await asyncio.sleep(2)
      await ctx.reply(f"{choice}")
```

There are no traceback errors but I don't know how to detect if it startswith "why" and make it lowercase both.

Answer (score 2):

You made a classic mistake: instead of `or` you should have used `and` because of the negations.

However this approach is not scalable. Luckily "why" only has 3 letters. Since you need `n^2` conditions, this will blow up fairly quickly.

Instead, you can use [`.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) to generate a string that is case-insensitive when used in comparisons:

```py
if not question.casefold().startswith('why'):
    await ctx.reply("Your question needs to start with `why` followed by the question")
```

Comment: `lower()` would do fine for English, though.